# Make curl/cat not scroll down when given long text?

Tags: terminal, curl, cat, text

I have made a program where I read the text from a url using `curl`. The problem is that when given texts that are larger than the terminal window, it automatically scrolls down to the bottom, I want to retrieve the text from `curl`, yet read from the beginning. I tried piping it to `cat` but it has the same problem.

One example are `man` pages, when I use `less`, I cannot search strings that is not currently seen with CMD + F, however, with `cat` I can since it outputs the entire thing and not like `less` which outputs a little, then more when I scroll down, but there's the problem that 99% of the time I want to begin reading from the top.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Many terminals have options in the preferences like "scroll on output", you need to un-check it.

Comment: @jimmij Yeah, I looked through the preferences before. I am using Apple Terminal, but to clarify I only want to do it for a specific program and not system-wide.

Comment: When output is piped into `less` (as is the case implicitly with `man`), you can type `/` and your query to jump to the requested text. You can also search back, search lines not containing the pattern, and of course, use regular expressions. You can then use `n` to jump to the next matching line. `man less` will tell you (a lot) more.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe it to `less`:

```
your_programm | less
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pipe the command to `less` with the 
`-F` or `--quit-if-one-screen` option which

> Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

The advantage of the `-F` option is that it saves you having to type <kbd>q</kbd> if the number of lines of text is less than the height of the screen.

```
curl URL | less -F
```

This would keep the start of the text at the top of the page and allow you to
scroll as you read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `more`

```
$ cat file | more
$ ./program | more
```

It displays the output from the beginning and you can go down by pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd> keys until you want to get. press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

Also you can use a different terminal as `terminator` and configure it to display "n" lines as you wish.

Comment: This does not output everything at once like I want to it to, I tried doing `man cat | more` and then search for "recognize multibyte" (which appears somewhere in the middle), and it wouldn't find it.

Comment: @DisplayName Have you tried something like saving the output into a file like `man cat >> cat_manpage.txt` and then enter with `vim` and then use the `/` to search for a string?